# spacy stemming on pandas df column not working

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy

How to apply stemming on Pandas Dataframe column

am using this function for stemming which is working perfect on string

```
xx='kenichan dived times ball managed save 50 rest'

def make_to_base(x):
    x_list = []
    doc = nlp(x)
    for token in doc:
        lemma=str(token.lemma_)
        if lemma=='-PRON-' or lemma=='be':
            lemma=token.text
        x_list.append(lemma)
    print(" ".join(x_list))    
make_to_base(xx)
```

But when i am applying this function on my pandas dataframe column it is not working neither giving any error

```
x = list(df['text']) #my df column
x = str(x)#converting into string otherwise it is giving error
make_to_base(x)
```

i've tried different thing but nothing working. like this

```
df["texts"] =  df.text.apply(lambda x: make_to_base(x))

make_to_base(df['text'])
```

my dataset looks like this:

```
df['text'].head()
Out[17]: 
0    Hope you are having a good week. Just checking in
1                              K..give back my thanks.
2          Am also doing in cbe only. But have to pay.
3    complimentary 4 STAR Ibiza Holiday or £10,000 ...
4    okmail: Dear Dave this is your final notice to...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Try `df['texts'] =  df['text'].apply(lambda x: make_to_base(str(x)))`

Comment: getting only "None" values in df['texts']

Comment: Then post an example dataframe.

Comment: updated question please check

Comment: Replace `print(" ".join(x_list))` with `return " ".join(x_list)`

Comment: ohhh tysm, can u post this as answer so i'll mark it

Comment: TBH i am so dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually return the value you got inside the `make_to_base` method, use

```
def make_to_base(x):
    x_list = []
    for token in nlp(x):
        lemma=str(token.lemma_)
        if lemma=='-PRON-' or lemma=='be':
            lemma=token.text
        x_list.append(lemma)
    return " ".join(x_list)
```

Then, use

```
df['texts'] =  df['text'].apply(lambda x: make_to_base(x))
```